# How to store $rootscope variable's value inside $scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-rootscope

Is it possible to use rootscope's vriable inside scope?
If yes then how?

For example, I want to set value of $rootScope.user_name in sub_menu property of scope.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []).run(function ($rootScope) {$rootScope.user_name = "A to Z Traders";$rootScope.user_role="Admin";});

app.controller('headerCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.menu=[
        {menu_name : "Seller's Name", menu_id: "user", sub_menu:[{$rootScope.user_name}, "Profile", "Add Brand Owner", "Logout"]}
    ];

});
```

Comment: `$scope.$root = 'something';`

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can.

Just inject $rootScope into the contoller ang get value from there

```
app.controller('headerCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) { 
$scope.menu=[ {menu_name : "Seller's Name", menu_id: "user", sub_menu:[{$rootScope.user_name}, "Profile", "Add Brand Owner", "Logout"]} ];
    }]);
```

But this is better solution to use service, where you will store data and functionality

Also you have to read about scopes inheritance